# Is $\sqrt x$ locally Lipschitz continuous everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Is $f(x)=\sqrt x$ locally Lipschitz continuous everywhere?

It is definitely not (globally) Lipschitz continuous. I wonder if it is locally Lipschitz continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider any interval $[0,\varepsilon)$ where $\varepsilon > 0$. For $x,y\in [0,\varepsilon)$, with $x < y$, we have 
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{|f(x)- f(y)|}{|x-y|} &= \frac{\sqrt{y} - \sqrt{x}}{y - x}\\
 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}}.
\end{align*}$$ Can you show that this can be made arbitrarily large, and if so, what can you conclude?

Comment: My guess: if we bound $x,y\in[0,a]$ then the answer is "yes", so $f(x)$ is not locally lipschitz. If we bound $x,y\in(0,a]$ then the answer is "no."

Comment: Even if $x,y>0$, we can make $\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}}$ arbitrarily large. For example take $x= \frac{1}{N+1}$ and $y = \frac{1}{N}$ for some $N$ sufficiently large.